# Photoshop Script: C#.Net call Ps 32 bit vs 64 bit

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, photoshop-script

I'm developing an application in C#.Net call to Photoshop.

My computer install 2 version of Photoshop 32bit and 64bit.

The application only call the 64bit version, that means when the 32bit version is already been opening, the application will raise an exception.

Could you show me how can I control the 32bit version of Photoshop in this case?
Thanks so much.

Here is code in VBScript

imagePath = "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg"
    Dim appRef
    Set appRef = CreateObject( "Photoshop.Application" )
    Set docRef = appRef.Open(imagePath)

Comment: I'm so sorry, the title is C# but content is VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

I took much time to find solution and that is:

1. If you use VBScript, you can run script in 32 bit mode

   > Open: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe
   >   Then run: cscript *.vbs
2. If you build C# Application, you can change target platform to x86